# Unable to change image In avatar using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My Objective is to show an image in avatar, If i could on the avatar icon and choose an image file then it should display the image in avatar. But i couldn't able to do that.

Can anyone help me in displaying the image in avatar?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like you are making any attempt to use the file other than saving it in your state.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - Sorry, unfortunately, i didn't written over there. I've updated my code. Could you please preview once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like:

```
onImageChange = event => {
let file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

console.log("File", file);

if (file === undefined) {
  console.log("File removed");
} else {
  this.setState({
    image: file
  });
}
```

};

and render

```
<Avatar src={this.state.image || '/static/images/avatar/1.jpg'} width="250" height="250" />
```

dont forget to revoke on unmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   URL.revokeObjectURL(this.state.image);
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this creates a memory leak. Might not be critical for the particular use case but in general you need to manually revoke object URLs for single page apps when they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the image saved to the state. As below

```
<Avatar src={this.state.image} width="250" height="250" />
```

In the constructor, load it with the default value.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        'image': '/static/images/avatar/1.jpg'
    };
  }
```

And the image change event should be

```
onImageChange = event => {
    let file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log("File", file);

    if (file == undefined) {
      console.log("File removed");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        image: file
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: He wants to change the image on click.

Comment: Isn't that achieved via `src={this.state.image}`?

Comment: By on click I mean the user selects an image from their file system and this image is shown inside the avatar. If the state stays the same it doesn't do anything, but show the same image.

Comment: @Vasanth - It's not changing for me

Comment: Yeah, I missed to add the `let file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);` in the onclick event. 
Editing the answer and adding it now.

Comment: The only difference is setting the default state value in the constructor. Let both answers be there. And the readers choose their preference